# Does "a little" (en) correspond to the same grammatical class as "ein wenig" (de)?

Tags: english, grammar, parts-of-speech, german

If you want to say in German, **"I speak a little German"**, you would say,

> Ich spreche ein wenig Deutsch.

The phrase "ein wenig" is reminiscent of the English phrase "a little", but what is interesting about "ein wenig" is that it is not an adverb proper. It belongs to a different class called an adverbial.

How would you classify the English phrase "a little"? Is it also an adverbial? And how would you classify the word "little" (in this usage) on its own? It does not seem to be an adverb here.

Comment: *Ich spreche ein wenig Deutsch.* is more akin to "I speak German a little."

Comment: If @MarkBeadles is correct, then _ein wenig Deutsch_ is not a constituent, whereas _a little German_ is. Consequently, _a little_ is a determiner (actually a phrase formed from an article and a quantifier), and not an adverb at all. _German_ is being treated as a quantified noun, like _a lot of German, not quite all German, an extremeliy small amount of German, a few phrases in German,_ and the like.

Comment: I think "ein bisschen" is the most common usage in this case, not "ein wenig"